A vandal edit by the answer author
I wonder what's going on here:

https://serverfault.com/a/932629/325117
https://serverfault.com/a/922350/325117
https://serverfault.com/a/933012/325117

The normal topic answer changed into absolutely unrelated text. Hacked or went nuts?
P.S. He also vandaled his questions:

From Samba to Windows - How to rebuild SYSVOL replication from scratch
Remote Desktop Printer Redirection: Driver not found


There is a lot of users that went to protest Stackoverflow affiliation with OpenAI. It’s maybe not related, but it’s a strange timing to do so (unless he got hacked)
Last week the mod team here suspended a lot that were trying to delete all their content, some tried the vandalism’s way sadly
The staff told us for this event to suspend for 30 days for the first offense, no warning, as editing back can be a long task when a lot of users do that.
I seen some users that after the vandalism, ask for their account to be deleted too.
In the suspend message I send the user to the legal/GDPR form as it’s the best way to protest IMO, vandalism is not, especially when SO already have data dump, and like the internet archive already have most of theses answers cached.

For the procedure to detect: As the sample used generated "blind text", one might write a tool to detect similar, taking some load from the review queues.
